# Insert character infront of each word in a string using C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a string, for example; "llama,goat,cow" and I just need to put a '@' in front of each word so my string will look like "@llama,@goat,@cow", but I need the values to be dynamic also, and always with a '@' at the beginning.
Not knowing a great deal of C++ could someone please help me find the easiest solution to this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by *insertable*'s comments, *(s?)* he's trying to get this code working...  So let me offer my take...

As with the others, I'm presuming each word is delimited by a single ",".  If you can have multiple character delimiters, you'll need to add a second find (i.e. find_first_not_of) to find the start/end of each word.

And yes, you could insert the '@' characters into the preexisting string.  But inserting for each word gets a little inefficient (O(N^2)) unless you're clever.  That sort of cleverness usually comes with a high maintenance/debugging cost.  So I'll just stick to using two strings...

(There ought to be some brilliant way to do this with STL algorithms.  But I'm sick and I just don't see how to accommodate insertion right now...)

References:  [C++-strings](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/start)      [C++-strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)     [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html)     [count_if](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/count_if.html)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define SHOW(X)  cout << # X " = " << (X) << endl

int main()
{
             //     0123456789_123456789_1234
  string  inString(",llama,goat,cow,,dog,cat");
  string  outString;

/* This code assumes inString.size() > 0 */

  const iterator_traits<string::iterator>::difference_type  numberOfWords
    = count_if( inString.begin(), inString.end(),
                bind2nd( equal_to<char>(), ',' ) )
       + 1;

  string::size_type  startIndex, endIndex;


  outString.reserve( inString.length() + numberOfWords );


  for ( startIndex = endIndex = 0;
        endIndex != string::npos;
        startIndex = endIndex + 1 )
  {
    outString += "@";

      /* No startIndex+1 here.  We set startIndex=endIndex+1 in the for loop */
    endIndex = inString . find_first_of( ",", startIndex );

    outString . append ( inString, startIndex,
                         (   (endIndex == string::npos)
                           ? string::npos : endIndex - startIndex + 1) );
  }

  SHOW( numberOfWords );
  SHOW( inString );
  SHOW( outString );
  SHOW( inString.size() );
  SHOW( outString.size() );
  SHOW( inString.capacity() );
  SHOW( outString.capacity() );
}
```

Comment: Hoorah! This works perfectly thank you, and thank you for the references also. I appreciate the suggestions from Drew and Jerry, too.

Answer (score 4):

For the moment, I'm going to assume that the words are always separated by commas. If that's correct, something like this should at least be fairly close:

```
// warning: untested.
std::string input("llama,goat,cow");
std::ostringstream o;

std::string word;

std::istringstream i(input);
while (std::getline(input, word, ','))
    o << "@" << word << ",";

std::string result(o.str(), o.str().size()-1);

// show the result:
std::cout << result;
```

Edit: there are two different functions named `getline`: one is a member of an `iostream`, and reads the input data into a "raw" array of char. The other is a global free function that reads the input data into a `std::string`. This is the one you want. To get it declared, you have to `#include <string>`.

Comment: This code looks interesting, but I am getting this error: llama.cpp:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::string&, std::string&, char)’ -- any idea what this means? thanks

Comment: After removing the std:: from std::getline, I get this error
llama.cpp:15: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’

Comment: I love the fact that your CPP file is named "llama.cpp"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++-style way:

Use the basic_string class in the standard library:
[basic_string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zz6weyz(VS.80).aspx)
('string' is an alias for basic_string)
You can use find_first_of() to find the first character that matches one of your wordbreak delimiters.  You can then use the append operator (+=) to append the segments of the string to a new string, and then append '@' symbols in between.

Here's a C-style way:

You could start with [strtok_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx)

Which will "tokenize" the string by searching for word-break delimiters like commas or spaces.  You'll then be able to copy the parts between the delimiters into another buffer and then put the '@' symbols between them as you go along

For that, I'd use [strcpy_s](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=strcpy_s&ac=8) to copy piece-by-piece into a new buffer.